# <lightning:datatable> Long Text Field Trucate Problem

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Has anyone been able to truncate a long text field in a `<lightning:datatable>`? I haven't been able to target the text in the object and i get a REALLY long field when putting in the `TextBody` section of an `EmailMessage`.